# React native async storage token goes missing after going back a screen and coming back auth is failing

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am new to react native, bear with me. when i click on categories(A) i navigate to new screen containing different subcategories(B) i am using get token on this page(B) and sending a request to fetch i can fetch successfully display sub categories. when i go back to screen A from there and clicking on categories again it's a error auth is failing in api call the token is missing, if i do this in a few minutes gap it works fine , just when i do immediately token is missing

```
useEffect(()=>{
    (async()=>{
       const token=await getToken() 
         setUserLToken(token) 
      })()
    }
    )
```

Comment: i can provide more details , please help

Answer (score 0):

You can save the token in the constant file, and whenever you call the API fetch the token from that file. so it will never give you the token missing file error.

Asyncstorage takes some time to get the value that's why you getting the token missing issue.

Create a File like AppManager.js and create prams in this file like below:

```
export var ConstantId = 
{
accessToken: '',
 
};
```

Now, whenever you set a token in Asyncstorage also save the token in the AppManger file like below:

```
import {ConstantId} from './AppManager';
ConstantId.accessToken = token;
```

Now, whenever a token is required just get it from the AppManger file, like below:

```
import {ConstantId} from './AppManager';
const token =  ConstantId.accessToken ;
```

One more thing, every time you launch the app just check if the token is stored in Ascynstorage or not if the token is there then fetch the token and store it in AppManager.js file from App.js file only, like below

```
 useEffect(() => {

     let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
            if (token != null) {
            ConstantId.token = token;
    }
})
```

Comment: i created a file name token.js with below code and imported token in file i am using still same error persists                                                                                  ` import { getToken } from '../services/AsyncStorageService';

export const token=getToken() //getting token from storage `

Comment: Please share the code, where you set the token in the getToken param.

Comment: ``const[userLToken,setUserLToken]=useState()
  useEffect(()=>{
    (async()=>{
      const token=await getToken() //getting token from storage
      setUserLToken(token) //store token in local storage
    })()
  }
  )``

Comment: is this what your asking for ???

Comment: Yes and That's the problem , you always trying to get token from Asyncstorage. See my answer and try, it will work for you.

Comment: Hi i tried above solution . i can get the token and re use it with this solution also , but the time span error is still persisting.

Comment: Time span error? can you please explain it

Comment: if i do this in a few minutes gap it works fine , just when i do immediately token is missing , the original question is about this only

Comment: Can we connect remotely for this?

Comment: sure , but how ? are you available now ??

Comment: how can i connect with you outside stack overflow??? can you drop any id

Comment: Please share your Anydesk id and time to connect.